# Warning: Undefined array key

Tags: php, array, undefined

Tengo un problema con mi código me arroja dos warnings:

> 1 Warning: Undefined array key "BURBUJA DE SILICON" in C:\xampp\htdocs\ASPELOPERACIONES\controlregistro.php on line 167
>
> 2 Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\ASPELOPERACIONES\controlregistro.php on line 167

Ya compare la escritura de los valores con los que tengo en la base de datos y corrobore que no existiera algun error y aun asi me sigue arrojando los warnings.

Agradeceria mucho su ayuda, comparto el codigo:

```
<?php
require "conexionAutoliv.php";

 ini_set('date.timezone','America/Mexico_City');
 $nombreacceso = $datosAutoliv['nombre_log'];
 $fechayhora = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
 $ingreso = mysqli_query($connectAutoliv,"INSERT INTO actividad (nombre_act,destino_act,fechahora_act)values('$nombreacceso','Control Registro','$fechayhora');");

 error_reporting(E_ALL^E_NOTICE);
if(isset($_POST['agregar'])){
 
    $defecto=$_POST['txtdefecto'];
    $cantidad=$_POST['txtcantidad'];

$_SESSION['articulos'][$defecto] = array(
      'defecto'=>$defecto,
      'cantidad'=>$cantidad
       );

echo "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-hover'>
<tr>
<th class='warning'>Defecto</th>
<th class='info'>Cantidad</th>
<th class='danger'>Eliminar</th>
</tr>";
foreach($_SESSION['articulos'] as $fila=>$elementos){
    echo "<tr>"
    ."<td>".$elementos['defecto']."</td>".
    "<td>".$elementos['cantidad']."</td>".
    "<td>"
  . "<input type='checkbox' class='' name='borrarthis[]' value='".$elementos['defecto']."'>"
  . "</td>"
    ."</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
else if(isset($_POST['borrar'])){
    
    foreach($_POST['borrarthis'] as $borrarthis){
        unset($_SESSION['articulos'][$borrarthis]);
        echo '<script>alert("¡Defecto eliminado!");</script>';
        echo "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-hover'>
<tr>
<th class='warning'>Defecto</th>
<th class='info'>Cantidad</th>
<th class='danger'>Eliminar</th>
</tr>";
foreach($_SESSION['articulos'] as $fila=>$elemento){
    echo "<tr>"
    ."<td>".$elemento['defecto']."</td>".
    "<td>".$elemento['cantidad']."</td>".
    "<td>"
  . "<input type='checkbox' class='' name='borrarthis[]' value='".$elemento['defecto']."'>"
  . "</td>"
    ."</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    }
    
}

else if(isset($_POST['guardar'])){

ini_set('date.timezone','America/Mexico_City'); 
$horaturno = date('H:i:s');

$supervisor = mysqli_escape_string($connectAutoliv, $datosAutoliv['nombre_log']);
if($horaturno >= '06:00:00' && $horaturno < '18:00:00'){
$turno = "1";
}else{
    $turno = "2";
}
$fecha = mysqli_escape_string($connectAutoliv,date('Y-m-d'));
$hora = mysqli_escape_string($connectAutoliv,date('H:i:s'));
$numeroparte = mysqli_escape_string($connectAutoliv, $_POST['txtnoparte']);
$numerolote = mysqli_escape_string($connectAutoliv, $_POST['txtlote']);
$numeroserie = mysqli_escape_string($connectAutoliv,$_POST['txtserial']);
$snp = mysqli_escape_string($connectAutoliv,$_POST['txtsnp']);
$burbuja_silicon = $_SESSION['articulos']['BURBUJA DE SILICON']['cantidad'];
if(empty($burbuja_silicon)){
    $burbuja_silicon = "0";
}else{}
$exceso_silicon = $_SESSION['articulos']['EXCESO DE SILICON']['cantidad'];
if(empty($exceso_silicon)){
    $exceso_silicon = "0";
}else{}
$gota_silicon = $_SESSION['articulos']['GOTA DE SILICON']['cantidad'];
if(empty($gota_silicon)){
    $gota_silicon = "0";
}else{}
$exceso_talco = $_SESSION['articulos']['EXCESO DE TALCO']['cantidad'];
if(empty($exceso_talco)){
    $exceso_talco = "0";
}else{}
$falta_talco = $_SESSION['articulos']['FALTA DE TALCO']['cantidad'];
if(empty($falta_talco)){
    $falta_talco ="0";
}else{}
$falta_silicon = $_SESSION['articulos']['FALTA DE SILICON']['cantidad'];
if(empty($falta_silicon)){
    $falta_silicon = "0";
}else{}
$falta_silicon_perfil_corte = $_SESSION['articulos']['FALTA DE SILICON EN EL PERFIL DE CORTE']['cantidad'];
if(empty($falta_silicon_perfil_corte)){
    $falta_silicon_perfil_corte = "0";
}else{}
$burbujas_patina = $_SESSION['articulos']['BURBUJAS DE PATINA']['cantidad'];
if(empty($burbujas_patina)){
    $burbujas_patina = "0";
}else{}
$hojuelas_patina = $_SESSION['articulos']['HOJUELAS DE PATINA']['cantidad'];
if(empty($hojuelas_patina)){
    $hojuelas_patina = "0";
}else{}
$falta_patina = $_SESSION['articulos']['FALTA DE PATINA']['cantidad'];
if(empty($falta_patina)){
    $falta_patina = "0";
}else{}
$tiras_patina = $_SESSION['articulos']['TIRAS DE PATINA']['cantidad'];
if(empty($tiras_patina)){
    $tiras_patina = "0";
}else{}
$tela_marcada = $_SESSION['articulos']['TELA MARCADA']['cantidad'];
if(empty($tela_marcada)){
    $tela_marcada = "0";
}else{}
$contaminacion = $_SESSION['articulos']['CONTAMINACION']['cantidad'];
if(empty($contaminacion)){
$contaminacion = "0";
}else{}
$arrugas_duras = $_SESSION['articulos']['ARRUGAS DURAS']['cantidad'];
if(empty($arrugas_duras)){
 $arrugas_duras = "0";   
}else{}
$inicio_rollo = $_SESSION['articulos']['INICIO DE ROLLO']['cantidad'];
if(empty($inicio_rollo)){
    $inicio_rollo = "0";
}else{}
$tela_rasgada = $_SESSION['articulos']['TELA RASGADA']['cantidad'];
if(empty($tela_rasgada)){
    $tela_rasgada = "0";
}else{}
$orificios_inf_desplazados = $_SESSION['articulos']['ORIFICIOS INFERIORES DESPLAZADOS']['cantidad'];
if(empty($orificios_inf_desplazados)){
    $orificios_inf_desplazados = "0";
}else{}
$orificios_sup_desplazados = $_SESSION['articulos']['ORIFICIOS SUPERIORES DESPLAZADOS']['cantidad'];
if(empty($orificios_sup_desplazados)){
    $orificios_sup_desplazados = "0";
}else{}
$trama_larga = $_SESSION['articulos']['TRAMA LARGA']['cantidad'];
if(empty($trama_larga)){
    $trama_larga = "0";
}else{}
$urdimbre_largo = $_SESSION['articulos']['URDIMBRE LARGO']['cantidad'];
if(empty($urdimbre_largo)){
    $urdimbre_largo = "0";
}else{}
$trama_corta = $_SESSION['articulos']['TRAMA CORTA']['cantidad'];
if(empty($trama_corta)){
    $trama_corta = "0";
}else{}
$urdimbre_corto = $_SESSION['articulos']['URDIMBRE CORTO']['cantidad'];
if(empty($urdimbre_corto)){
    $urdimbre_corto = "0";
}else{}
$linea_negra_desplazada = $_SESSION['articulos']['LINEA NEGRA DESPLAZADA']['cantidad'];
if(empty($linea_negra_desplazada)){
    $linea_negra_desplazada = "0";
}else{}
$rollo_pegado = $_SESSION['articulos']['ROLLO PEGADO']['cantidad'];
if(empty($rollo_pegado)){
$rollo_pegado = "0";
}else{}
$objetos_extranos = $_SESSION['articulos']['OBJETOS EXTRAÑOS']['cantidad'];
if(empty($objetos_extranos)){
    $objetos_extranos = "0";
}else{}
$loop = $_SESSION['articulos']['LOOP']['cantidad'];
if(empty($loop)){
    $loop = "0";
}else{}
$blip = $_SESSION['articulos']['BLIP']['cantidad'];
if(empty($blip)){
    $blip = "0";
}else{}
$hilo_decolorado = $_SESSION['articulos']['HILO DECOLORADO']['cantidad'];
if(empty($hilo_decolorado)){
   $hilo_decolorado = "0"; 
}else{}
$filamentacion = $_SESSION['articulos']['FILAMENTACION']['cantidad'];
if(empty($filamentacion)){
    $filamentacion = "0";
}else{}
$hilo_flotante = $_SESSION['articulos']['HILO FLOTANTE LARGO']['cantidad'];
if(empty($hilo_flotante)){
    $hilo_flotante = "0";
}else{}
$tela_mallugada = $_SESSION['articulos']['TELA MALLUGADA']['cantidad'];
if(empty($tela_mallugada)){
    $tela_mallugada = "0";
}else{}
$hilo_atravesado = $_SESSION['articulos']['HILO ATRAVESADO']['cantidad'];
if(empty($hilo_atravesado)){
    $hilo_atravesado = "0";
}else{}
$falta_linea_antitwist = $_SESSION['articulos']['FALTA DE LINEA ANTITWIST']['cantidad'];
if(empty($falta_linea_antitwist)){
    $falta_linea_antitwist = "0";
}else{}
$bolsas_incompletas = $_SESSION['articulos']['BOLSAS INCOMPLETAS']['cantidad'];
if(empty($bolsas_incompletas)){
    $bolsas_incompletas = "0";
}else{}
$hilo_atravesado_continuo = $_SESSION['articulos']['HILO ATRAVESADO CONTINUO']['cantidad'];
if(empty($hilo_atravesado_continuo)){
    $hilo_atravesado_continuo = "0";
}else{}
$hilo_atravesado_multiple = $_SESSION['articulos']['HILO ATRAVESADO MULTIPLE']['cantidad'];
if(empty($hilo_atravesado_multiple)){
    $hilo_atravesado_multiple = "0";
}else{}
$hilo_atravesado_garganta = $_SESSION['articulos']['HILO ATRAVESADO EN GARGANTA']['cantidad'];
if(empty($hilo_atravesado_garganta)){
    $hilo_atravesado_garganta = "0";
}else{}

$capturarcaja = "INSERT INTO registro_cajas (supervisor_caja,turno_caja,fecha_caja,hora_caja,numeroparte_caja,numerolote_caja,numeroserie_caja,snp_caja,burbuja_silicon,exceso_silicon,gota_silicon,exceso_talco,falta_talco,falta_silicon,falta_silicon_perfil_corte,burbuja_patina,hojuelas_patina,falta_patina,tiras_patina,tela_marcada,contaminacion,arrugas_duras,inicio_rollo,tela_rasgada,orificios_inf_desplazados,orificios_sup_desplazados,trama_larga,urdimbre_largo,trama_corta,urdimbre_corto,linea_negra_desplazada,rollo_pegado,objetos_extranos,loop,blip,hilo_decolorado,filamentacion,hilo_flotante_largo,tela_mallugada,hilo_atravesado,falta_linea_antitwist,bolsas_incompletas,hilo_atravesado_continuo,hilo_atravesado_multiple,hilo_atravesado_garganta) values('$supervisor','$turno','$fecha','$hora','$numeroparte','$numerolote','$numeroserie','$snp','$burbuja_silicon','$exceso_silicon','$gota_silicon','$exceso_talco','$falta_talco','$falta_silicon','$falta_silicon_perfil_corte','$burbujas_patina','$hojuelas_patina','$falta_patina','$tiras_patina','$tela_marcada','$contaminacion','$arrugas_duras','$inicio_rollo','$tela_rasgada','$orificios_inf_desplazados','$orificios_sup_desplazados','$trama_larga','$urdimbre_largo','$trama_corta','$urdimbre_corto','$linea_negra_desplazada','$rollo_pegado','$objetos_extranos','$loop','$blip','$hilo_decolorado','$filamentacion','$hilo_flotante','$tela_mallugada','$hilo_atravesado','$falta_linea_antitwist','$bolsas_incompletas','$hilo_atravesado_continuo','$hilo_atravesado_multiple','$hilo_atravesado_garganta')";

if(mysqli_query($connectAutoliv, $capturarcaja)){
   
    echo "<script>alert('¡Registro agregado!'); window.location='controlregistros.php'</script>";
    unset($_SESSION['articulos']);
    mysqli_close($connectAutoliv);
}else{
    echo "<script>alert('¡Error, verifique datos!'); window.location='controlregistros.php'</script>";
    unset($_SESSION['articulos']);
    mysqli_close($connectAutoliv);
}
}
?>
```

Por los warnings que arroja tambien no puedo ver si son los unicos o existen mas, ademas de que no se registran los datos.

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. Dos cosas: 1) Son warnings, no errores. El código se sigue interpretando normalmente. 2) Que estos warnings se muestren no condiciona el que se muestren otros si los hubiere. No se entiende entonces la frase final de tu pregunta. Y esto posiblemente se debe a que tu PHP está configurado pa revisar esto y pintar los warnings. EN producción normalmente no se hace. Ahora, no sabemos qué tienes en sesión cuando sale ese mensaje. un `print_r` o var_dump de $_SESSION ayudaría a ayudarte

Comment: Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante 
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta). 
La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas!